# Is pandas connection to yahoo-finance broken? (AGAIN?)

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

A quick question. I am trying to download historical data for some stocks from yahoo-finance by using pandas. The code is, as always:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import datetime as dt
import fix_yahoo_finance  

df= pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=dt.datetime(2014, 1, 1), end=dt.date.today())
```

The result I obtain is an empty dataframe "df", which was not the case until yesterday.

Is anyone having the same issue? Thanks

---

UPDATE: Yahoo fixed this today, but the system is so unreliable these days that I encourage everyone to find alternatives for data, especially if your work depends on it

---

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an empty data frame because the yahoo-finance API has been taking down. You can read more about it [here](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Yahoo-Finance-help/Is-Yahoo-Finance-API-broken/td-p/250503/page/3).

Comment: this is an old issue which was (apparently) solved with the fix-yahoo-finance method (see: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fix-yahoo-finance ) 
The code above was working until yesterday, it stopped working today for me

Comment: Ah, sloppy reading from my side. Didn't know there was a parser fix for this.